# Dynamically running ClamAV's clamscan on file uploads with PHP

Tags: php, security, file-upload

Stack,

I want to scan each file that gets uploaded via my php upload script with clam anti-virus's clamscan tool.  I think I've got a good script written but I wanted to run it past you guys.

So assuming that the file I'm sending to this php upload script is named "uploadedfile" does the following code make sense?

```
<?php

$safe_path = escapeshellarg('/tmp/' . $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']);
$command = 'clamscan ' . $safe_path;
$out = '';
$int = -1;
exec($command, $out, $int);

if ($int == 0) {
   // all good, code goes here uploads file as normal IE move to
permanent directory etc;
} else {
   unlink('/tmp/' . $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']);
header(Location: http://www.domain.com/uploadform.php?error=your-file-was-infected-pal);
}

?>
```

Also, will clamscan find php shells as well as traditional good old malware?

Thanks!

### Update - found the answer

I answered my own question but don't have the reputation to officially do so.  Here is the anser:

For those who come after.  I've tested this script using the EICAR test virus file http://eicar.org/86-0-Intended-use.html and after a few tweaks it works. The return variable $int is what tells you whether or not the file is safe or not. If $int is 0, no virus was found, if $int is 1, a virus was found.  However, there are some changes that I had to make the script work (I updated the $safe_path variable to be correct), here is the working script:

```
<?php

$safe_path = escapeshellarg($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']);
$command = 'clamscan ' . $safe_path;
$out = '';
$int = -1;
exec($command, $out, $int);

if ($int == 0) {
   // all good, code goes here uploads file as normal IE move to
permanent directory etc;
} else {
  //whatever you need to do if a virus is found.
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this!

Comment: Special upvote for `escapeshellarg` . Many devs forget this one and it is tremendously important - security aware dev should exclude possibility of arbitrary code execution through things like `exec`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that if your server runs a clamav daemon (clamd) it may be possible to use clamdscan instead of clamscan as proposed, this usage is faster since use virus signatures already loaded by clamd.

Comment: This answer was a time bomb ;-) Yes that's actually what I ended up using. clamscan took like 5-6 seconds to start up, clamdscan is practically immediate.

Comment: Also, I have found that opening a socket connection to the clamd directly was resulting in inconsistent output (ClamAV v0.98.4 on Solaris Sparc) when recursively scanning directories.  Using the clamdscan binary worked every time.

Comment: Thanks!! seriously helpful :)

Comment: Side note: If you use `clamd` the user that runs `clamd` needs to have permission to file that you want to scan.

Answer (score 1):

Just be careful. If your clamscan becomes outdated you'll get feedback in the output:

It will look like this:

```
LibClamAV Warning: ***********************************************************
LibClamAV Warning: ***  This version of the ClamAV engine is outdated.     ***
LibClamAV Warning: *** DON'T PANIC! Read http://www.clamav.net/support/faq ***
LibClamAV Warning: ***********************************************************
```

Also depending on the version of clamscan the "result" might look like this (and you'll need to parse it accordingly):

```
[filename]: OK

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: x
Engine version: x.x.x
Scanned directories: 0
Scanned files: 1
Infected files: 0
Data scanned: x.xx MB
Data read: x.xx MB (ratio 0.00:1)
Time: x.xx sec (0 m x s)
```

Comment: I ran the script using a normal image.jpg file and the eicar test virus file and the $int return value will return as a 0 if the file is safe and a 1 if the file is infected. So that's what I'm basing the rest of the script actions on.

Comment: In that case it looks good. Just remember to keep your definitions up to date. If you want to test against some shell code, just download a couple from here http://www.exploit-db.com/search/?action=search&filter_page=1&filter_description=&filter_exploit_text=&filter_author=&filter_platform=0&filter_type=4&filter_lang_id=0&filter_port=&filter_osvdb=&filter_cve=

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of trouble with permissions when trying to run this with clamdscan. I found a solution for the permissions problem here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ClamAV

This changed this line:

```
$command = 'clamscan ' . $safe_path;
```

to:

```
$command = 'clamdscan  --fdpass ' . $safe_path;
```

Seemed to successfully pass a good file and flag an EICAR file.